# htaccesss rewrite won't work

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help rewriting the following url's:

example.com/news/top/2/

example.com/news/top/

This is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) index.php?view=$1&task=$2
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?view=news&task=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^news index.php?view=news
```

I thought this would work but whenever I visit = example.com/news/top/2/
and I try to echo out the $_GET['page'] it says that the variable is not defined.

Can somone pleas help  with this nerve breaking problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use end anchor `$`

```
RewriteEngine on

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=news&task=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1&task=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ index.php?view=news [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) index.php?view=$1&task=$2
```

needs a `$`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?view=$1&task=$2
```

because it is matching beyond just `/dir1/dir2`